# Array like object converted to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying with JavaScript to do what I have done with jQuery for error handling for an API response.

I wrote this piece of code in jQuery that does what I want it to (different project):

```
var response = e.responseJSON;
$.each(response.errors, function(index, value){
  var div = $("#error_" + index);
  div.html(value[0]).addClass('error');
});
```

Then I tried to convert the code to JavaScript instead of jQuery, but I seem to be having issues with the object like array conversion to an array. For an `e.forEach` loop.

The code I currently have is this:

```
.catch(function(response){
  let e = Object.values(response.response.data)
  let data = Array.from(e[1])
  console.log(e)
  console.log(data)
});
```

When I log `data` it returns an empty array. While logging `e` returns the object like array.

[image]

I guess what I am looking for is, what am I doing wrong and is there a better way of going about what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Not answer, just learning myself - why is it important that it's javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: The second code seems to do different things than the jQuery code. The first code block iterates over `reponse.errors`, while the second gets the first element of `response.response.data`, and then converts that value to an array. Completely different, unrelated things.

Comment: Just don't really want to add the dependency to the project. Plus I want to learn how to do it without, I feel too reliant on jQuery and want to move towards learning plain JavaScript

Comment: This is a good idea to shy away from jQuery if you intend on learning ReactJS as they are not the most compatible.

Comment: What is e[0] giving you?

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: I hope posting a push link is ok. https://puu.sh/xDM5I/91e080a30a.png I think this should answer everyone's questions so far.

Comment: `e` looks like an array, but `e[1]` is not array-like. Why are you trying to convert it to an array?

Comment: Ok, so I guess I overlooked that. `e` is an array, but `e[1]` is not an array. But from what I was reading don't I need an array for `.forEach`? So wouldn't `e[1]` need to be converted to an array? Also, I guess I need to go look at a definition for array-like again. Sorry, still kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e[1]` is a non-array-like object, so `Array.from(e[1])` doesn't really make sense. I think what you want is:

```
let e = Object.values(response.response.data);
for (var index in e[1]) {
    var div = document.getElementById('error_' + index);
    div.innerHTML = e[1][index][0];
    div.classList.add("error");
}
```

Comment: I'd add `if (e[1].hasOwnProperty(index))` before considering `index`

Comment: @Frederik.L That's not really needed for objects created from JSON, there are never any inherited, enumerable properties.

Comment: Sorry wasn't looking at StackOverflow for a few. It would seem that that code produces an index is not defined error. Thank you for your help, still trying to get a grasp on JavaScript.

Comment: @kennyL `index` can't be undefined, it's being assigned by the `for` loop.

Comment: Which line is line 11922? Also, I forgot the `var` declaration in my original post, and fixed that a few minutes ago, but it shouldn't affect this.

Comment: line 11922 was the `for(index in e[1])` it is uncompressed web pack for now

Comment: You accepted the answer, does that mean the undefined variable error has gone away?

Comment: It does, I got it working for my project with a couple of changes to how I output to the error to the div. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```js
var response = {"error1": "my error", "error2": "another error"}

example(response)

function example(response) {
  Object.keys(response).map(function(key) {
    console.log(key)
    console.log(response[key])
  })
}
```